# How to set minimum for Jenkins Plot Plugin

Tags: plot, jenkins, phploc

I use Jenkins and its Plot Plugin to generate statistics.

Example: 
For every Build I plot the line of codes. Lets say I have like 500.000 lines and it changes about +-100 lines per build.

Since the plot y-axis always starts with 0 the whole plot is meaningless. It looks like 1 straight line.

Same goes for other metrics, if the value is too high.

Question: is there any configuration to set minimum y-axes to the minimum value?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I think the answer to your question is currently 'no'.

First of all, the documentation does not give any hints towards such an option.

Secondly, Given that the Jenkins Plot Plugin uses [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) for the plotting, the setting of a range for the Y-axis should be done using the '[getRangeAxis](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#getRangeAxis%28%29)' function. A [search in the source-code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plot-plugin/search?q=rangeAxis&type=Code) does not reveal a call to this function.

Lastly, you do not seem to be the only one that has this problem. [Issue JENKINS-2841 asks for the same functionality](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2841), but appears not be solved yet.